# Battling a 'same policy' CORS when doing a post request with Express

Tags: node.js, express, post

I have an issue when I want to create a new account on my website. Everything works fine when hosted as localhost but as soon as it's hosted on AWS, I have the famous Same-Policy CORS issue.

To create an account, I have an OPTIONS request and a POST request. The OPTIONS request is empty and after hanging a few minutes I finally get the Cross-Origin failure alert.
But when I try to log on to an existing account (created with PhpMyAdmin), the OPTIONS and POST requests work out fine.

Also, while creating an account if I use an existing email address already in the database, I will have a message telling me that this email address is already in use, so front and back are communicating.

It's a front done with React and the Back is node.js server working with Express (v6).

I've set up the npm CORS package, tried a lot of setups found on the internet but I never manage to go through with the account creation.
Any help would be much appreciated!

You'll find below two screenshots, one when I log on and one when I try to sign up.
I'll put also my server.js configuration file with my several attempts.

Thanks!

[image: Creating Account Gone Wrong]

[image: Logging In]

**Server.js** file - Version 1

```
// ImPORT_BACK
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

const app = express();
const {
  PORT_BACK, PORT_FRONT, HOST, // FRONT_URL,
} = process.env;

const Origins = ['http://becomepote.fr', 'http://becomepote.fr:3000/api/$/', '/\.becomepote\.fr$/'];

// CORS
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: Origins,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS' ],
    allowedHeaders: ['Origin', 'Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'X-Requested-With', 'Accept', 'Access-Control-Request-Method', 'Access-Control-Request-Headers' ,'X-CSRF-Token', 'Cache-Control', 'Pragma'],
    exposedHeaders: ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'Content-Range', 'X-Content-Range'],,
    preflightContinue: true,
    credentials: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 201,
  }),
);

// BODYPARSER
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
  }),
);

// SESSION
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  name: 'myCookie',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  },
}));

// COOKIE
app.use(cookieParser());

// File Upload
app.use(fileUpload({ useTempFiles: true }));

// Start on assigned port
app.listen(PORT_BACK, () => {
  console.log(`Welcome, this server running at http://${HOST}:${PORT_BACK}`);
});

// Routes
app.use('/api', require('./api/users').router);
app.use('/api', require('./api/question').router);
app.use('/email', require('./email/email.model').router);
```

**Server.js** file - Version 2

```
// ImPORT_BACK
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

const app = express();
const {
  PORT_BACK, PORT_FRONT, HOST, // FRONT_URL,
} = process.env;

const Origins = ['http://becomepote.fr', 'http://becomepote.fr:3000/api/$/', '/\.becomepote\.fr$/'];

const corsOptions = {
  origin: Origins,
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS' ],
  allowedHeaders: ['Origin', 'Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'X-Requested-With', 'Accept', 'Access-Control-Request-Method', 'Access-Control-Request-Headers' ,'X-CSRF-Token', 'Cache-Control', 'Pragma'],
  exposedHeaders: ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'Content-Range', 'X-Content-Range'],
  preflightContinue: true,
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 201,
  //maxAge: 240,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.options('/api/register', cors(corsOptions), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("Preflight request allowed");
});

// BODYPARSER
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
  }),
);

// SESSION
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  name: 'myCookie',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  },
}));

// COOKIE
app.use(cookieParser());

// File Upload
app.use(fileUpload({ useTempFiles: true }));

// Start on assigned port
app.listen(PORT_BACK, () => {
  console.log(`Welcome, this server running at http://${HOST}:${PORT_BACK}`);
});

// Routes
app.use('/api', require('./api/users').router);
app.use('/api', require('./api/question').router);
app.use('/email', require('./email/email.model').router);
```

Users.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const router = express.Router();
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
const User = require('../Models/Users');
const withAuth = require('../middleware');

/**
   * CREATE - Route for creating a user account, checking if email
   * already exist and using bcyrpt to hash password
   * @param {object} req
   * @param {object} res
   * @returns {object} user object
   */
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const { pseudo, email, password } = req.body;
  User.query()
    .where('email', email)
    .select('email')
    .then((user) => {
      if (user.length > 0) {
        res.status(409).send('Email already exist');
        return;
      }
      if (!email || !password || !pseudo) {
        res.status(400).send({ message: 'One or more values are missing for creating account' });
      }
      else {
        User.query()
          .insert({
            pseudo,
            email,
            password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10),
          })
          .then((newUser) => {
            // SESSION
            const userSession = {
              id: newUser.id,
              email: newUser.email,
            };
            req.session.user = userSession;
            const { session } = req;
            const response = {
              status: 'Created account',
              session,
            };
            res.status(201).send(response);
            res.json(response);
          });
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => res.status(500).send({
      message:
          err.message || 'An error has occurred while creating your account.',
    }));
});

/**
   * LOGIN - Route to connect a user
   * @param {object} req
   * @param {object} res
   * @returns {[object]} user object
   */
router.post('/connect', (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  User.query()
    .where('email', email)
    .select('id', 'email', 'password')
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user.length > 0) {
        res.status(401).send('Email is wrong');
        return;
      }
      const passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user[0].password);
      if (!passwordIsValid) {
        res.status(401).send('Password is wrong');
      }
      else {
        // SESSION
        const userSession = {
          id: user[0].id,
          email: user[0].email,
        };
        req.session.user = userSession;
        const { session } = req;
        const response = {
          status: 'Logged in',
          session,
        };
        res.status(200).send(response);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => res.status(500).send({
      message:
           err.message || 'Login was unsuccessful, please try again',
    }));
});
```

Comment: re: "empty CORS req"   check this answer  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316180/empty-request-body-with-post-using-cors-with-a-node-app-on-openshift

Comment: @RobertRowntree thanks a lot for pointing me towards that topic. I had already seen it but didn't manage to get any further (app.options('*', cors()) didn't do anything for me).


This time around I understood a bit more what was needed with the preflight requests.
I do manage to get further down the road when creating an account. The issue I have now is that my database (MySQL) is not storing any information. I'll keep digging around.

I'll post here my final code once it's working.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out, my issue wasn't regarding a CORS error.
As stated from the beginning, my issue with a CORS error only occurred when I tried to create an account on the new user page (an options then a post request).
But everything worked fine once on the login page (options then a post request).

So since, I found it strange that only my register page would require `app.options('*', cors());` to work as suggested (and it didn't work), I looked in my USER model done with Knex to check out the register query.
Again, there wasn't any issue with my model and I finally figure out that a few columns in my database (MySQL) needed to be set as null (firstname, lastname, age, presentation). Information which are required later on in the sign up process as my create an account page only asks for a nickname, email and password.

That setup error would lead my options and post requests when creating an account to hang and finally crash as a Same-Origin Policy error (CORS)... quite strange.

In the end this is my file that I'm using to set up CORS.

**Server.js file**

```
// IMPORT_BACK
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

const app = express();
const {
  PORT_BACK, PORT_FRONT, HOST, // FRONT_URL,
} = process.env;

// CORS OPTIONS
const Origins = ['http://becomepote.fr', 'http://becomepote.fr:3000'];


const corsOptions = {
  origin: Origins,
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Origin', 'Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'X-Requested-With', 'Accept', 'Access-Control-Request-Method', 'Access-Control-Request-Headers'],
  exposedHeaders: ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'Content-Range', 'X-Content-Range'],
  credentials: true,
};

// BODYPARSER
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
  }),
);

// SESSION
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  },
}));

// COOKIE
app.use(cookieParser());

// FILE UPLOAD
app.use(fileUpload({ useTempFiles: true }));

// Start on assigned port
app.listen(PORT_BACK, () => {
  console.log(`Welcome, this server running at http://${HOST}:${PORT_BACK}`);
});


// CORS OPTIONS APPLIED
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Routes
app.use('/api', require('./api/users').router);
app.use('/api', require('./api/question').router);
app.use('/email', require('./email/email.model').router);
```